# dynamical system and well potential : $\dot x(t)=-\nabla \left(\frac{x(t)^2}{2}\right).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f'(y)=\frac{y^2}{2}$ and consider the ODE $$\dot u(t)=-f'(u(t)).$$
This is often represented by the draw below, but I don't understand the connection. So I understand that at the point $x=u(t)$ the speed of the particle has the same speed that $f$ at $x$. But the scheme below looks quite wrong, since the speed of $f$ at $x=0$ is $0$ whereas, the speed of the particle at $x=0$ is normally maximal. So in what this draw represent the situation ? I'm very confuse with that.

To fix idea, such an example can be found page 4 (it's in the case of exit from potential well with white noise).

[image]

Comment: It does look wrong, $f'(y) = y$ so the ODE is $u' =- u$? which is not what's in the picture. Maybe it should instead be $f'(y) = y^2/2$

Comment: @CalvinKhor: yes, absolutely, thank you.

Comment: In my lecture I have exactly the scheme of my post... maybe it's a mistakes...

Comment: @Winther: Look page 4 of [this document](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~pavl/lec_react_rate.pdf) (it's in case of exit of potential well with white noise, but except de brownian motion it's the same equation).

Comment: Ok good. The other point still stands unresolved. The title and body doesn't match. Is is $u' = -\nabla(u^2/2) = -u$ or is it $u' = -u^2/2$ (as you have in the body).

Comment: Why do you think the particle should have maximal speed at $x=0$? That would hold true for if the equation was one the fomr $\ddot{x} = - \nabla V$, but not for the ODE you got.

Comment: It's really $u'=-\nabla (u^2/2)$ (i.e. $u'=F(u)$ where $F$ is conservative). May be the draw gives me truble, but as I see it the particule fall along the wall). Other wise, the draw doesn't make any sense... @Winther

Comment: A system $\dot{x} = -V'(x)$ is equivalent to the $\ddot{x} = -V_{\rm eff}'(x)$ where $V_{\rm eff} = -\frac{1}{2}V'(x)^2$ which you can interpret as a particle rolling in a potential $V_{\rm eff}$ (and for which the velocity would be maximal at the bottom). For your example the effective potential would be $-x^2/2$ so the drawing should be inverted if you want this analogy to get intuition about the solution. However it's probably easier to look at it from the normal dynamical system perspective(i.e. $\dot{x} = -V'(x)$ has fixpoints where $V$ has max/min points).